# Why is $\kappa({A^{-1}})$ important and what does it tell us?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations, condition-number

We need the condition number of a matrix $\kappa(A)= \frac{\text{max}_{\vert\vert \vec{y} \vert\vert =1}\vert\vert A \vec{y} \vert\vert}{\text{min}_{\vert\vert \vec{y} \vert\vert =1}\vert\vert A \vec{y} \vert\vert}$ to help us understand how much the solution vector will change if there is a small change in the input matrix or output vector. It can also be used to see that there are rounding errors made in solving $A \vec{x} = \vec{b}$ when working with floating point numbers.

However, why would we need to know about the condition number of the inverse of $A$? Why is $\kappa({A^{-1}})$ important?

Answer (score 1):

> However, why would we need to know about the condition number of the inverse of $A$? Why is $\kappa(A^{-1})$ important?

The question rather silly, given that by definition $\kappa(A)=\|A\|_2 \cdot \|A^{-1}\|_2 = \kappa(A^{-1})$.